# Url parameter for each data on click in AngularJS using controllers and routing

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I am trying to fetch movie details from api which works fine, now i want to click on each films and display the film details on click parameters in filmdetail page. I have "url" in api which i want to use as param
my project structures are as follows:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="mainApp">


    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

home.html

```
<div ng-controller="upcomingFilmsCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="film in films">
            {{film.filmName + ' ' + film.filmReleaseDate}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div ng-controller="filmsInTheatresCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="film in films">
            <a href="#films/{{film.url}}">{{film.filmName + ' ' + film.filmReleaseDate}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
Hello world <a href="#/filmdetail">films</a>
```

filmdetail.html

```
//Individual film details
    <div ng-controller="fillmDetailsCtrl">
            {{filmName}}
            {{filmReleaseDate}}
            {{otherFilmStuf}}

    </div>
```

controller.js

```
 var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);        
     //upcomingFilms Controller
     app.controller('upcomingFilmsCtrl', function($scope, $http){
        $http.get('upcoming-films.php')
        .success(function(response){
            $scope.films = response.upcomingFilms;  
        });

     });

     //filmsInTheatres Controller
     app.controller('filmsInTheatresCtrl', function($scope, $http){
        $http.get('films-in-theatres.php')
        .success(function(response){
            $scope.films = response.filmsInTheatres;    
        });

     });

    //config

    app.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'home.html'    
        })
        .when('/films', {
            templateUrl: 'filmdetail.html'  
        })
        .otherwise('/anotherPage', {
            redirectTo: '/'
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [$location.search()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search) to modify the query parameters in the URL when an item is clicked. This method is a getter/setter, so if you pass it an object, those key=value pairs will be added as URL query params...but if you pass no parameters, it will return the current query params as an object.